# haproxy and socat sudo

Tags: haproxy, sudo

I created a test user and want to limit this "test" user to run only the following command via visudo.

```
echo "show stat" | socat stdio /var/run/haproxy.sock
```

visudo

```
test    ALL=(root)NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/socat stdio /var/run/haproxy.sock
```

ls -lat /var/run/haproxy.sock

```
srwxr-xr-x 1 munin haproxy 0 May 22 22:32 /var/run/haproxy.sock
```

I ran the following command

```
test#sudo echo "show stat" | socat stdio /var/run/haproxy.sock
```

The error message

```
2013/05/22 23:13:14 socat[21289] E connect(3, AF=1 "/var/run/haproxy.sock", 23): Permission denied
```

May I know what was incorrectly configured in visudo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your pipe, only echo is run with elevated privileges, I believe you need a sudo before socat.

Answer (score 7):

The `echo` is running as `root`, but the `socat` isn't.  Try this instead:

```
echo "show stat" | sudo socat stdio /var/run/haproxy.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a normal (non-privileged) unix socket like:

```
    stats socket /var/run/haproxy/socket.sock mode 666
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid `permission denied` if you change configuration like below.

```
stats socket /var/run/haproxy/socket.sock level admin
```

**Result:**

```
echo "set server"|nc -U /var/run/haproxy/socket.sock
Require 'backend/server'
```